# Flask-SocketIO and SocketIO Client; Client Emit event doesn't trigger consistently

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, flask-socketio

Whenever I click on my send button, the emit event doesn't trigger consistently (sometimes it triggers, sometimes it doesn't). It does trigger when I spam click on my send button.

Here is my server.py

```py
@socketio.on('message')
def message(message_data):
    print(message_data)
    room = message_data['channel']
    emit('broadcast', message_data, room=room)
```

And here is my client.js which is supposed to trigger the send event

```js
socket.on('connect', function (){
                socket.emit('join channel', {
                    'channel_id': localStorage.getItem('channel_id')
                })
            })

            $("#send").on('click', function (){
                prevent_blank_text()
                socket.emit('message',{
                    'message': $("#message").val(),
                    'user': localStorage.getItem('channel_user'),
                    'channel': localStorage.getItem('channel_id'),
                    'timestamp': new Date().toLocaleString()
                }, function (){
                    $("#message").val('')
                })
            })
```

Note: the connect event is decoupled from the click event, I just included it there just in case that's where the problem is stemming from.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Apparently bootstrap's btn-large is what's causing the problem, it wasn't a socketio problem

```html
<button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
```

This fixed my send button